# How can I create custom dropdown menu

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I am new to WPF. I want to create a dropdown menu similar to this image. I am not getting from which control should I start the implementation of ControlTemplate.

I guess It is a Hyperlink with a ContextMenu.

Comment: @RaviKavaiya: yes It can atleast let me started. Please share your suggestions. FYI, this image is taken from Twitter.

Comment: do you useing html jquery or css?

Comment: @RaviKavaiya : You didn't get my question properly. I am using WPF. I need xaml code.

Comment: Man, I hate when web applications do this. It's so inconvenient and difficult to use. I always chalk it up to a limitation of the platform. Now you're going to start doing it in a desktop app where better alternatives exist? Ugh.

Comment: @CodyGray: Ya you are right, But all we need is to satify customer.

Answer (score 2):

[WPF Popup control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) is exactly what you are looking for:

```
<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="True">
    <Label Name="myLabel" Content="Language: English" 
          Background="Black" Foreground="White"/>
    <...other controls you like.../>
</Popup>
```